# C - DCT Transform

Tags: c, matrix, dct

I have a exercise,write a simple c programing about dct transform (read img and break in to block 8x8 matrix - do dct - do idct - recreate the picture, and it must be nearly identical to the original image)
I done with step2,3 -  dct and idct but now i dont know how to read img and break it into a matrix,device matrix to 8x8 and recreate picture form idct.
I've wrote it to read img and break into 8x8,but not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("D:\img.jpg","rb");
  if(!fp)
  printf("Can not load image");
  int width = 400;
  int height = 600;
  unsigned char buff[(400*600)];
  unsigned char image[400][600];
  size_t n = fread( buff, sizeof(buff[0]), sizeof(buff), fp );
  fclose(fp);
  for(int i =0; i < height; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < width;j++)
    {
      image[j][i] = buff[(i*width)+j];
    }
  }
  unsigned char dividedimage[(400*600)/(8*8)][8][8];
  for(int i = 0; i < height/8; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < width/8;j++)
    {
      for(int k = i*8, l = 0; k < (i*8)+8; k++,l++)
      {
        for(int m = j*8, n = 0; m < (j*8)+8; m++,n++)
        {
          dividedimage[(i*(width/8))+j][n][l] = image[m][k];
        }
      }
    }
   }

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      printf("%8.3f ", image[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

anyone can tell me how to break img into blocks 8x8 matrix and recreate picture :((.thank you

Comment: You can't load a jpg this way (well you can, the result just isn't pixels) so it already fails there

Comment: Use a JPG loading library, or to simplify things, pre-convert the image into raw form and go from there